# Simulate on click feature with javascript disabled

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have the following input radio button in my page(among other things) which displays a select input box upon checking that radio button.

This is implemented using javascript. Now the client also wants this select box to be displayed on clicking the radio button if javascript is disabled.

Is that even possible without javascript?
The only other way i see is have an intermediate form submit button which does handling? I am not sure how to go about it.
Any help would be appreciated!

here is my code so far:

```
<td style="visibility:<?= $Visible;?>" id="rmark1"><span>Mark question?</span></td>
<td style="visibility:<?= $Visible;?>" id="rmark2" nowrap>
<input type="radio" id="mail1" name="mail" value="GE" onClick="showMark();" <?= $check;?> >
            <select id="ReturnMarkings" name="ReturnMarkings">
                <option value=''>Please Choose One:</option>
                <option value='1' <?= $Array[1];?>>Mark 1</option>
                <option value='2' <?= $Array[2];?>>Mark 2</option>

            </select>

function showMark() {
    var pcRMark1=document.getElementById('rmark1');
    var pcRMark2=document.getElementById('rmark2');

    pcRMark1.style.visibility="visible";
    pcRMark2.style.visibility="visible";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bfavaretto and @lostsource answers are great-- but this doesn't require PHP and works in Chrome:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #ReturnMarkings {
        display: none;
    }
    :target {
        display: inline !important;
    }
</style>

<input type="radio" id="mail1" name="mail" value="GE"><a style='width:12px; height:12px; display:inline-block; margin-left:-12px;' href='#ReturnMarkings'></a>  

<select id="ReturnMarkings" name="ReturnMarkings">
                <option value=''>Please Choose One:</option>
                <option value='1'>Mark 1</option>
                <option value='2'>Mark 2</option>
            </select>
```

props to @lostsource for the radio button link code

demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/MT5db/

**edit**:

As pointed out in the comments, this doesn't actually 'check' the radiobutton. Here's a cheap hack to fix, untested outside jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MT5db/1/

Comment: good stuff! just out of curiosity would it be possible to modify the radio button state via CSS as well?

Comment: Lot of great answers here! I am selecting Jeff's answer because that worked for me. I also thank lostsource and bfavaretto!

Comment: @lostsource ah, didn't even notice that! not sure how to check a radio button using css, but here's a cheap hack! http://jsfiddle.net/MT5db/1/

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the browser's CSS support, this could work:

```css
#ReturnMarkings{ display: none; }
#mail1:checked+#ReturnMarkings { display:inline; }​
```

See [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wMYXL/).

It relies on the CSS adjacent sibling selector, which is supported by IE8+ according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=adjacent%20sibling). I also relies on the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3achecked) pseudo-class, which is IE9+ according to MDN.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve a similar effect you would need to use a combination of PHP and CSS. The following changes will have to be applied. (hold on tight, this will NOT be pretty)

The radio button needs to be changed to a link, assuming your page is called form.php the link will have to become like this:

```
<a href='form.php?showmark=true'>Show Mark</a>
```

Just below your select box add the following logic, by which PHP will inject CSS which will make your drop down visible:

```
<select id="ReturnMarkings" name="ReturnMarkings">
     <option value=''>Please Choose One:</option>
     <option value='1' <?= $Array[1];?>>Mark 1</option>
     <option value='2' <?= $Array[2];?>>Mark 2</option>
</select>

<?
   if(isset($_GET["showmark"])) {
?>

        <style type='text/css'>
        #ReturnMarkings {
            visibility:visible!important;
        }​
        </style>
<?
   }
?>
```

I do not particularly suggest mixing PHP / Markup / CSS, but this might be your only solution

Comment: you don't need PHP to do this, you can make the first link go to #ReturnMarkings, and use the :target selector

Comment: if OP really wants a checkbox, he can clickjack the click by placing the <a> tag over it.. but i'm not going to explain that because I think this answer is much better then mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/13384384/149636

Comment: edited my comment and +1 to your answer-- but you can't use <a> tag over a radio button. the other answer is good, but doesn't work in most major browsers

Comment: well, you can, kind of http://jsfiddle.net/GpRtr/5/ .. granted i'm assuming the width and height

Comment: ah great idea-- just added an answer of my own

Answer (score -1):

No, not possible without JavaScript.